# HTML form - how to use GET method to also generate email?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, get

I am hoping this question has a simple answer.

I have an HTML form on a website that uses the GET method to send the variables within the form to a PHP page, i.e.

```
<form name="create_landing_page" action="/landing-page/" method="get">
```

What I would like to do is also generate an email when that form is submitted so I have the dynamic URL written down somewhere, since we don't save them to a database. I tried putting some PHP on the landing page that automatically generates an email when the page loads using this method: [How to send an email notification when a page is visited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021183/how-to-send-an-email-notification-when-a-page-is-visited), but I'm not receiving any of my test mails.

Is there a very simple way I can either grab the variables from the submitted form and email them, or grab the URL from the landing page and email that?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should share the code you have that isn't working..

Comment: Yes, code would be helpful. Also, are you getting any error messages? PHP's `mail` function is not always available / configured on all web hosts.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apparently I can't send email on this server with the mail() function, so I will have to find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to retrieve the values from the form and then email those values:

NOTE: I did not clean inputs in any way - so if you're going to use a database make sure to clean them up!

**LandingPage.html**

```
<form name="create_landing_page" action="/landing-page/" method="get">
<input name="email_address" value="Enter your email" />
<input name="name" value="Enter your name" />
</form>
```

**landing-page(.php)**

```
        if(isset($_GET['email_address']) && !empty($_GET['email_address'])){
    $emailAddress = $_GET['email_address'];
    }

        if(isset($_GET['name']) && !empty($_GET['name'])){
    $name= $_GET['name'];
    }

        $to      = $emailAddress;
        $subject = 'the subject';
        $message = 'hello ' . $name;
        $headers = 'From: youremail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: youremail@example.com' . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        if(!mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers))
        {
            die('There was an error sending out the email');
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apparently I can't send email on this server with the mail() function, so I will have to find another solution.

Comment: There is a good chance you're just not using it correctly - mail is setup if it's working on your wordpress installation ....

Comment: Why would my mail() function die then when I'm testing it?

Comment: Perhaps you've got some NULL values in there for variables - make sure all variables have the values you expect them to.

Answer (score 1):

The reason may be that your system does not have a mail service on it, try:

```
$result=mail($mailAddress,$subject,$content);
if(!$result)
    die("Mail subsystem error!");
```

Comment: I got the error message...does this mean that I'm unable to generate emails directly from the PHP?

Comment: That means you are on a system (most likely a localhost - your windows computer) that does not know how to send email on its own.
The "mail()" function really only makes some system call to "mail transfer agent"
From personal experience, on my home computer (running Windows + Apache) i am unable to send emails, while from the hosting account on the internet i usually am. Solution would be to try different hosting provider or install a mail service if you own the computer.

Comment: Hmm...I'm using a Linux server, and this is through a WordPress install. I have the Contact Form 7 plugin, and can send emails fine through that on this same site. I'm not sure why I wouldn't be able to send email vial mail() or wp_mail().

Comment: @user1997781 HI, just searched around for some answers on Mr.Google. try reading through: [LinuxQuestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/php-mail-not-working-506205/) also read up similar question in here at [Stack Overflow - sendmail working but php mail is failing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819865/sendmail-working-but-php-mail-is-failing). Sorry i'm not more help there, but i don't know much about setting up a mail deamons (and nothing about wordpress)

Comment: Thanks for the help! I may need to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the full path to the page a script is running including any parameters, you can use `_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`.

Sending mail can be tricky based on where your app is hosted and how your server is configured. The `mail()` command is sometimes disabled by hosting services to reduce spam. If you're using a shared hosting service, you may want to check if `mail()` is available.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Apparently I can't send email on this server with the mail() function, so I will have to find another solution.